# What is the best Index to my Query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, indexing

I have millions and millions of data in **JC_ItemDailySalesParent** table. When I do the grouping It's loading more than 5 min but it was not completed.

The total rows affected is may be **500,000** records(Without grouping)

```
select  pp.ItemLookupCode,
            StoreID,
            sum(Qty) TotalQuantity,
            sum(ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
            sum(ExtendedCost) ExtendedCost
            into #temp_tt
FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[JC_ItemDailySalesParent] pp
WHERE   (Time>=CONVERT(datetime,'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000',102))  and 
        (Time<=CONVERT(datetime,'2015-01-31 00:00:00.000',102))
group by pp.ItemLookupCode,StoreID
    order by pp.ItemLookupCode
```

> I created the index for **Time**.

Comment: I think your query will improve if you capture the cut-off dates in a variable, so the `convert` function doesn't have to be used for every row. Also, if you are inserting in another table, why do you `order by`?

Comment: Just look at the execution plan.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Can you give me an example?

Comment: @mohamedfaisal the downvote was probably because to solve performance problems, a lot more information is required. Such as table properties, execution plan, hardware etc. etc.

Comment: Fastest results are usually achieved by using covering index - add all other resulting columns (itemlookupcode and storeid as part of index, other three columns as included ones) to your Time index and then SQL doesn't need to read other data at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an index on `Time`, doing the following may improve performance in your query:

```
declare @DateStart datetime = CONVERT(datetime,'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000',102)
,       @DateEnd datetime = CONVERT(datetime,'2015-01-31 00:00:00.000',102)

select  pp.ItemLookupCode,
            StoreID,
            sum(Qty) TotalQuantity,
            sum(ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
            sum(ExtendedCost) ExtendedCost
            into #temp_tt
FROM    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[JC_ItemDailySalesParent] pp
WHERE    Time>=@DateStart  and 
         Time<=@DateEnd
group by pp.ItemLookupCode
,        StoreID
order by pp.ItemLookupCode
```

Answer (score 0):

what is pk of this table ?

yes it necessary to provide data type and if you already other indexes on this table.
apart from above correted query.

i) create NCI on time include (Qty,ExtendedPrice,ExtendedCost)

ii) Create one NCI on ItemLookupCode,StoreID include (Qty,ExtendedPrice,ExtendedCost)

First do i) and only create one NCI on ItemLookupCode,StoreID
and check the actual query plan again and again using diff. parameter.

If index is not being use then implement i) and ii) fully and check query plan.

i think this is how you fine tune any query.